# How to check any http request from any apps on device

Tags: android, android-internet

I have to check any http request from any app on the device for internet, so that i can display back if i have cached any of these requests on the device.

Can you please let me know how to do that

-regards,
Manju

Answer (score 0):

You can't (unless you root the device and get into the kernel). If you think about it for a second, you'd realize what security hole that would be to allow any app monitor the http traffic of other apps.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe  wireshark could do the thing you want.
But at first you must root your device.

Comment: device is not rooted, any other options ?

Comment: No way.  Maybe the others have anyway.